# C++ declare pointer constant as enumeration value

Tags: c++, pointers, enums

How to declare a pointer constant as an enumeration value?? (As simplest way)

I had tried like this, but it's throwing compile error.

What's wrong with in this code?

```
enum class Platform : uint32_t
{
    PF_WINDOWS = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t>((const char* const)"Windows"),
    PF_LINUX = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t>((const char* const)"Linux")
};
```

Comment: Why do you need them to be pointer values?

Comment: Why not define them as const char* and use them? Why is this required?